# Height percentage using divs

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with divs and percentages.  I do not understand how to expand or set the divs so it would be the full size of the screen.  It is stuck at the top of the browser when I view it.  What do I do?

```
HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>BasicArchitect</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"
        </head>
       <body>
       <div id="container">

       <div class="header">

       </div>

       </div>

      </body>
      </html>

CSS
    body{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
    #container{
        height:90%;
        width:100%;
        margin:auto;
        background-color:white;
        border-style: solid;
}
    .header{
        height:50%;
        margin:auto;
        background-color: red;
        border-style: dashed;
}
```

Comment: You also need to add `html{height:100%;}`.

Comment: It worked.  Thank you very much.  Can you explain why I needed to add html{height:100%;}?

Answer (score 0):

Sizing the body to `height: 100%` doesn't really do anything unless if you set `html`'s height to 100% as well. The measurement you are looking for is Viewport Height, or `vh` for short.

You want to replace `body { height: 100% }` with `body { height: 100vh }`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from percentages, you can use `viewport` units like `vh` and `vw`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  height: 90vh;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
}

.header {
  height: 50vh;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>BasicArchitect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">

      <div class="header">

      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```